# .NET 4 function : Function argument question

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

I'm following a [tutorial on MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-4) on the .NET 4 framework.  The tutorial created a function like this...

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace vohministries.Helpers
{
    public static class HtmlHelpers
    {
        public static string Truncate(this HtmlHelper helper, string input, int length)
        {
            if (input.Length <= length)
            {
                return input;
            }
            else
            {
                return input.Substring(0, length) + "...";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea what`this HtmlHelper helper` means or represents in the function argument.  Is this something new in .NET 4?  I think it may be extending the HtmlHelper class but I'm not sure...Could someone explain the syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). (Been in since C# 3.0):

> Extension methods enable you to "add"
>   methods to existing types without
>   creating a new derived type,
>   recompiling, or otherwise modifying
>   the original type. Extension methods
>   are a special kind of static method,
>   but they are called as if they were
>   instance methods on the extended type.
>   For client code written in C# and
>   Visual Basic, there is no apparent
>   difference between calling an
>   extension method and the methods that
>   are actually defined in a type.

Comment: This is mostly bang-on, but they're a 3.5 feature ;)

Comment: Ooops! Thx. Could  have sworn I'd used them in 2.0 !

Answer (score 0):

You can call that extension method in two ways:

```
HtmlHelpers.Truncate(helper, input, length)
```

OR

```
helper.Truncate(input, length)
```